# Periodic JQuery update in Seaside

Tags: jquery, smalltalk, seaside

I am using Seaside (2.8 in Squeak 4.2) and am normally updating like this:

```
html div 
    onClick: ((html jQuery: '#asdf') load html: [:h|h text: 'qwer'])
    ; with: 'asdf'.
```

But this time, i have to **update a div periodically**.

I have used PT's `periodicalEvaluator` in another project, however in this one I can not, I have to stick to JQ.

I tried to use JQInstance's `delay:millis` in all combinations i could think of:

```
onClick: (((html jQuery id: 'chattertext') delay: 1000; yourself) load html: [:h| self renderTextOn: h])
; onClick: (((html jQuery id: 'chattertext') delay: 1000) load html: [:h| self renderTextOn: h])
; onClick: (((html jQuery id: 'chattertext') delay: 1000; load) html: [:h| self renderTextOn: h])
and others
```

for some reason the update is instantaneous instead of after **1000 millis which i need**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the example coming with the JQuery functional test suite:

```
JQRepeatingFunctionalTest>>#renderContentOn: html
  html paragraph
    script: (html jQuery this load
      html: [ :r | self renderTimeOn: r ];
      interval: 1 seconds); 
  with: [ self renderTimeOn: html ]
```

The example is running [here](http://demo.seaside.st/javascript/jquery/repeatedajaxcalls).

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `delay` function only applies to effects [1].

To achieve what you want, just use Javascript's setTimeout or setInterval functions:

```
onClick: (((html jQuery id: 'chattertext') load html: [:h| self renderTextOn: h]) timeout: 1000)
```

[1] http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: First, thanks for your answer. But it shows an error: `WAError: The option 'timeout' is not supported in JQLoad. Either use #ajaxSetup to configure default values, or the more powerful version with #ajax.`. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: That is indeed an unfortunate method override on the JQAjax wrappers. Can you try the following? (((html jQuery id: 'chattertext') load html: [:h| self renderTextOn: h]) addDecoration: (JSTimeout duration: aDuration))    Let me know if it works, then I will adapt my answer.